# Error handling with APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eventbrite

I been working with eventbrite and eventful apis, as I become more specific with the requests, the apis error out for the api that cannot perform the task. I want it to skip that error and still execute the remaining api. How do i raise exceptions if one fails?

My code:

```
#eventbrite api
@eb_auth_tokens = { app_key: 'TN7HUH76XZTXHI2AV5'
               }
    @eb_client = EventbriteClient.new(@eb_auth_tokens)
    @event_search = @eb_client.event_search(
                        #city: "syracuse",
                        postal_code: "13201",
                        within: "1",
                        within_unit: "M",
                        date: "2013-06-19 2013-06-25",
                        #keywords: "business, economy",
                        max: "100"
                        )
 #eventful api
 client = EventfulApi::Client.new(:oauth_token => 'token', :oauth_secret => 'token secret')
    response_hash = client.get('/events/search/', {
                        location: "10007",
                        within: "200",
                        units: "mi", 
                        date: '2013061900-2013062700',
                        #keywords: "business,economy",
                        #sort_order: "date",
                        page_size: '15'
                        })

    events =response_hash['events']
    @perevents = events['event']
```

Comment: Wanting to skip the first task if it fails vs raising exceptions -- seems like these are two opposites sides of the spectrum. Which would you like to focus on?

Comment: Skip any task that doesn't work

Comment: @JesseWolgamott I just applied begin in the beginning of each api and a rescue end at the end of each and it seems to suffice. Is that correct? is there a better way?

Comment: extract each task to a method, rescue each method.

Comment: each task to a method within the index method?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am recommending.